# how to avoid color shifting for hardware acceleration with chrome

Tags: google-chrome, frontend, hardware-acceleration

I used figma and adobe xd for designing and prototyping and after lose some of my hair trying to see why colors where not displaying correctly when coded, I got to see that it was hardware acceleration enable setting on chrome.

I look for disabling it with js or other way and as far as I found there is no way, I'm concern that user see very different displays due to this bug, is there a way to get around this? a css property that does not cause this or some weird hack to keep the colors true?

I find this a big issue for front-end designers